# How to get BluetoothGattCharacteristic value format type?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, android-ble

While developing an application for IOT tried communicating with a BLE peripheral device. Using BLE Lollipop API.

Each BluetoothGattService can provide different BluetoothGattCharacteristic, each representing a certain value which can be Read, Write or Notified.

[Value is communicated in various formats](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/format-types). But there is no way to know which format a particular Characteristic is encoded in.

I thought this mKeySize could be a solution but, it is neither accessible nor being used inside BluetoothGattCharacteristic to determine any value output.

```
 /**
 * Returns the deisred key size.
 * @hide
 */
/*package*/ int getKeySize() {
    return mKeySize;
}
```

I made use of following functions to check out desired output.

```
   String getStringValue (int offset)
   getIntValue(int formatType, int offset)
   getFloatValue(int formatType, int offset)
```

But they were only useful in certain cases where communicated data was not complex e.g

[DeviceName](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/characteristics/Pages/CharacteristicViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.characteristic.gap.device_name.xml) -> (getStringValue)

[BatteryLevel](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/characteristics/Pages/CharacteristicViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.characteristic.battery_level.xml) ->(getIntValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8,0))

They were easy bait but characteristics like  [Peripheral Preferred Connection Parameters](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/characteristics/Pages/CharacteristicViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.characteristic.gap.peripheral_preferred_connection_parameters.xml) nowhere to be recognized.

I have already used a static hashmap to retrieve Specification Name based on their assigned number which seems to grow bigger in size to include all adapted BLE profile.

**I would like to know are there any better methods available to fetch BluetoothGattCharacteristics value appropriately?**

**Also, there are different ways to write characteristic value and at certain places specific value, how should I approach this uncertainty?**

Check out this android application [BLEScanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.macdom.ble.blescanner), to a major extent can perform Read and Write.